Trouble figuring out input arguments to SciPy RegularGridInterpolator for 2D interpolation
I'm trying to interpolate 2D data to find the value of Z at point (X,Y) as if it were a 2D lookup table.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import io

xi, yi = 100, 100; # test points I want to evaluate the interpolator object at


# the 2D data copied from google sheets and pasted into Jupyter notebook generates this dataframe:
values = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,221,220,219,218,217,217,215,215,215,217,217,218,218,219,220,221,222,222,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,219,218,217,215,215,210,210,210,215,217,217,217,218,219,220,221,222,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,210,207,207,207,210,215,215,217,218,219,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,223,215,210,207,205,205,207,207,210,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,207,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,207,205,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,218,217,215,207,207,215,215,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  '''), header=None);

# these are the X and Y values corresponding to the X and Y dimensions of the data (values).
X = np.linspace(0, 2600, values.shape[1]);
Y = np.linspace(0, 1700, values.shape[0]);

Yi, Xi = np.meshgrid(Y, X);

interp = RegularGridInterpolator((Y, X), values); # X and Y are switched here because Y corresponds to the rows of the dataframe and X corresponds to the columns but I'm matching the SciPy syntax.

interp(np.array([[xi], [yi]]).T) # this is the portion I'm having trouble with

I don't understand what the format of the arguments I'm putting into the interp object. From the documentation, it says that the input is a tuple of ndarrays. But this example shows evaluating the interp object on a np.array and on a tuple of lists. I've tried those and a combination of everything between but I'm still not getting it right... thanks for your help.
The code as described above returns the following error:
InvalidIndexError: (array([1]), array([1]))

I'm trying to return the interpolation for a single point (every iteration of a for loop, for example). Or for all points at once after the for loop if it's necessary to do it that way.

The documentation you point to is using an array.
You are using a dataframe. Based on 'How to perform interpolation on 2d grid from dataframe in python?', you can use the values attribute of the dataframe:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import io

xi, yi = 100, 100; # test points I want to evaluate the interpolator object at


# the 2D data copied from google sheets and pasted into Jupyter notebook generates this dataframe:
values = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,221,220,219,218,217,217,215,215,215,217,217,218,218,219,220,221,222,222,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,219,218,217,215,215,210,210,210,215,217,217,217,218,219,220,221,222,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,210,207,207,207,210,215,215,217,218,219,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,223,215,210,207,205,205,207,207,210,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,207,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,207,205,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,218,217,215,207,207,215,215,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
  '''), header=None);

# these are the X and Y values corresponding to the X and Y dimensions of the data (values).
X = np.linspace(0, 2600, values.shape[1]);
Y = np.linspace(0, 1700, values.shape[0]);

Yi, Xi = np.meshgrid(Y, X);

interp = RegularGridInterpolator((Y, X), values.values); # X and Y are switched here because Y corresponds to the rows of the dataframe and X corresponds to the columns but I'm matching the SciPy syntax.

Alternatively, you can convert the DataFrame to a numpy array and then.
transpose the array to match the expected shape, (Y, X), with the addition of values_array = values.to_numpy().T and then adjusting the interpolation call too interp = RegularGridInterpolator((X, Y), values_array).

Thank you! Ironically, I converted it to a numpy array to implement a simpler solution. Good to know that will also help me properly implement the approach I posted about here.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import io


# Create the DataFrame from the 2D data
values = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,221,220,219,218,217,217,215,215,215,217,217,218,218,219,220,221,222,222,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,219,218,217,215,215,210,210,210,215,217,217,217,218,219,220,221,222,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,210,207,207,207,210,215,215,217,218,219,219,220,221,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,223,215,210,207,205,205,207,207,210,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,207,210,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,216,215,207,205,203,203,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,217,217,215,207,205,205,207,210,212,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,218,218,217,215,207,207,215,215,215,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
'''), header=None)
# Test points
xi, yi = 100, 100  # Points to evaluate

# Create the X and Y coordinates
X = np.linspace(0, 2600, values.shape[1])
Y = np.linspace(0, 1700, values.shape[0])

# Create the interpolator with values as a NumPy array
interp = RegularGridInterpolator((Y, X), values.to_numpy())

# Evaluate the interpolator at the point (xi, yi)
result = interp(np.array([[yi, xi]]))  # Note: (Y, X) => (yi, xi)

print("Interpolated value at (", xi, ",", yi, "):", result[0])


RegularGridInterpolator :
Assumes that the data points are structured
on a regular grid (i.e., data points are aligned in a grid-like fashion).
But it is not ideal for irregular or sparse data.
BallTree :
Handles irregular or unstructured datasets efficiently.
It's better suited for non-grid-based data,
like scattered or randomly distributed points. The query performance of BallTree is logarithmic O(log⁡n), which is Excellent.

Solution using BallTree :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import io

# Sample 2D data
values = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,221,220,219,218,217,217,215,215,215,217,217,218,218,219,220,221,222,222,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,219,218,217,215,215,210,210,210,215,217,217,217,218,219,220,221,222,222
'''), header=None)

values = values.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Automatically calculate max X and Y values based on data dimensions
# 100 per column (we can adjust this multiplier based on our data)
max_x_value = values.shape[1] * 100 
# 100 per row (we can adjust this multiplier based on our data)
max_y_value = values.shape[0] * 100  

# Create X and Y coordinates using max_x_value and max_y_value
X = np.linspace(0, max_x_value, values.shape[1])
Y = np.linspace(0, max_y_value, values.shape[0])

# Create a meshgrid for the coordinates
Y_grid, X_grid = np.meshgrid(Y, X)
points = np.vstack((X_grid.ravel(), Y_grid.ravel())).T  # Shape (n_points, 2)

# Create the BallTree
tree = BallTree(points)
# Define the test points
test_points = np.array([[100, 100], [200, 300], [1300, 1500]]) 
# Query the BallTree for nearest neighbors
distances, indices = tree.query(test_points, k=4)
# Extract the values for interpolation
neighbor_values = values.values.ravel()[indices]
# Simple interpolation using a mean of neighbors
interpolated_values = np.nanmean(neighbor_values, axis=1)
# Print the results
for i, point in enumerate(test_points):
    print(f"Interpolated value at {point}: {interpolated_values[i]}")
    
"""
Interpolated value at [100 100]: 223.0
Interpolated value at [200 300]: 223.0
Interpolated value at [1300 1500]: 223.0
"""    

Using KD TREE :
# Sample 2D data
values = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,221,220,219,218,217,217,215,215,215,217,217,218,218,219,220,221,222,222,222
223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,223,219,218,217,215,215,210,210,210,215,217,217,217,218,219,220,221,222,222
'''), header=None)

values= values.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
max_x_value = values.shape[1] * 100
max_y_value = values.shape[0] * 100
X = np.linspace(0,max_x_value,values.shape[1])
Y = np.linspace(0,max_y_value,values.shape[0])

Y_grid,X_grid = np.meshgrid(Y,X)

points = np.column_stack((X_grid.ravel(),Y_grid.ravel()))

kdTree = KDTree(points)
#Turn to 1D as we are using KD TREE
values_1D = values.values.flatten()

test_points = np.array([[100, 100], [200, 300], [1300, 1500]]) 
distance,indices = kdTree.query(test_points,k = 4 )
neighbor_values = values_1D[indices]
print(neighbor_values)
'''
[[223 223 223 223]
 [223 223 223 223]
 [223 223 223 223]]
'''
interpolated_values = np.nanmean(neighbor_values, axis=1)  

for i, point in enumerate(test_points):
    print(f"Interpolated value at {point}: {interpolated_values[i]}")

'''
Interpolated value at [100 100]: 223.0
Interpolated value at [200 300]: 223.0
Interpolated value at [1300 1500]: 223.0

'''

